# How to reformat web.config files with ReSharper

Tags: xml, web-config, resharper

I have *very* large web.config files, and I've decided to reformat them for ease of reading and updating.

Currently, my keys look like this:

```
<Setting key="favicon" value="favicon.ico"/>
<Setting key="DisableUserCache" value="false" />
```

What I'd like is to be able to auto-format them to look like this:

```
<Setting key="favicon"                    value="favicon.ico"/>
<Setting key="DisableUserCache"           value="false" />
```

Is anyone familiar enough with ReSharper setttings to help me set that up? I'm not even sure where to look in the Options to start setting something like this.

Comment: (Yes - I know that ReSharper is evil.)

Comment: Why do you say that? Resharper is an awesome tool and has a lot of powerful features that you should get to know and use everyday.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper cannot do this type of formatting, your best bet is to try the [Code alignment](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd?SRC=VSIDE) extension for Visual Studio.